# A sequence of Gaussian random vectors converges to a Gaussian random vector

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

> Suppose $\left\{X_n : n \in N\right\}$ is a sequence of Gaussian random vectors and $\lim_n X_n = X$, almost surely. If $b := \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} EX_n$ and $C := \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \textrm{Cov}X_n$ exist, then $X$ is Gaussian with mean $b$ and covariance matrix $C$.

This is proposition 12.15 (p. 351) from the appendix to Mörters & Peres's "Brownian Motion" (the version that's available on Peres's site.) The authors do not provide an explicit proof; rather, they state that a proof can be given along the lines of the argument that is used to prove an earlier proposition, namely:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are $d$-dimensional Gaussian vectors with $EX = EY$ and $\textrm{Cov}(X) = \textrm{Cov}(Y)$, then $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

I'll appreciate any help in proving proposition 12.15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow} X\Rightarrow X_{n}\overset{d}{\rightarrow }X\Rightarrow \Phi_{n}(x)\rightarrow \Phi(x)$ pointwise where $\Phi_n(\cdot),\ \Phi(\cdot)$ are the characteristic functions of $X_n,X$ respectively. Now, Since $X_n$ are Gaussian, $\Phi_n(x)=e^{jx^T\mu_n-x^TC_nx/2}$ where $
\mu_n:=EX_n,\ C_n:=\mbox{Cov}(X_n)$ Then, since $\exp(\cdot)$ is a continuous function, we have, pointwise, $$\Phi(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Phi_n(x)=e^{jx^T\mu-x^TCx/2}$$ which shows that $X$ is a Gaussian random vector with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $C$.